# error when I make peer in my virtual box

Tags: docker, hyperledger

I want to run hyperledger project in my virtual box.

First, I successfully `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` my virtual box.

And then, I `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric`.

Next step, I `make peer`. But I get following error.

> vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ make peer
>
> Makefile:45: *** "No docker in PATH: Check dependencies".  Stop.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you had some problems when setting up your virtual box. Try running the `setup.sh` script found in `fabric/devenv`.

If it still fails, try manually installing docker:

```
sudo apt-get install docker
```